# Access parent activity views from fragment in tablayout?

Tags: android, android-layout, kotlin, android-fragments, android-activity

I am using `TabLayout` with `ViewPager`. I have 3 fragments and 3 tabs. I want to access the `FloatingActionButton` in `activitymain.xml` file.

In every fragment I write a code like this:

```
    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        val fab :View= (requireActivity() as MainActivity).findViewById(R.id.fab_main)

            fab.setOnClickListener {
                Toast.makeText(context,"Fragment1",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()  
            }
        }
```

But when I click the `FloatingActionButton` in every fragment it gives me the same Toast message which is related to the last fragment. I want to perform different actions in every fragment when I clicked the button.

Comment: You should call the floating action button in activity. You can access current fragment via viewpager or fragment manager.

Comment: Have you tried setting the click listener in the `onResume()` ?

Comment: But I need to call floating action buttons in fragments because I need to handle it inside fragments.

Comment: @MohamedHamdy now I tried your solution and it worked. Thank you so much! But I didn't understand what made the differences to put the listener in onResume(). Can you explain it please ?

Comment: @AbdulsametKılınçarslan To understand this part add logging in the `onCreateView` and `onResume` this will make it easier to understand the difference, then go and read @Daniel.Wang 's comments

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use FragmentStatePagerAdapter for tab function

```
class TabAdapter(fm: FragmentManager) : FragmentStatePagerAdapter(fm, BEHAVIOR_RESUME_ONLY_CURRENT_FRAGMENT) {
..........
}
```

It will be make Fragment call onResume when the fragment is active.
So you can like this in Fragment

```
override fun onResume() {
    super.onResume()

    val fab :View= (requireActivity() as MainActivity).findViewById(R.id.fab_main)

    fab.setOnClickListener {
        Toast.makeText(context,"Fragment1",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()  
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you Daniel! Now it worked when I put the code inside the onResume() method. Thanks! But why we need to put the code inside onResume() method ?

Comment: FragmentStatePagerAdapter will call onResume when fragment is active. So if you put the setOnClickListener in onResume method, fab button event will occurred in this listener.

Comment: If you put the event listener code in onCreate, click event listener is overrided by other fragment. you have three fragment now. so first event listener will be discarded by second event listener in other fragment. But if you put code in onResume, event listener will be set when fragment is active. It will be worked correctly.

Comment: I am currently using ViewPager2. My ViewpagerAdapter class extends FragmentStateAdapter because FragmentStatePagerAdapter is deprecated. Sometimes, when I click floating action button inside one of 3 fragments, it opens different thing than I expected.